# What is the advantage of using sudo apt-get autoremove over a cleaner app?

Tags: apt, cleanup

I'm not sure what `sudo apt-get autoremove` does, but have read that you should use this command to remove any unnecessary packages.

One of the processes I saw was to use `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then use something like [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net) to remove temp files etc.

Can you explain what `sudo apt-get autoremove` actually does and is there any advantages of using this command over something like BleachBit or [Ubuntu Tweak janitor](http://ubuntu-tweak.com) by themselves?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

> what `sudo apt-get autoremove` actually does

Whenever you install an application (using `apt-get`) the system will also install the software that this application depends on. It is common in Ubuntu/Linux that applications share the same libraries. When you remove the application the dependency will stay on your system.

So `apt-get autoremove` will remove those dependencies that were installed with applications and are no longer used by anything else on the system.

> is there any advantages of using this command over something like Bleachbit or Ubuntu Tweak janitor?

- Bleachbit or Ubuntu Tweak janitor are graphical interfaces.
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` is a command

Using one option does not exclude the other: I would assume BB and UTJ use  `sudo apt-get autoremove` (in some sort of way) to remove dependencies. So it is not a question of "any advantages." It is a matter of preference: are you a command line type of person or are you a GUI type of person?

By the way: `deborphan` is another tool to clean your system.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. In my own experience running `sudo apt-get autoremove` is safer than using something like Bleachbit, i (and a friend of mine) have run into problems after using Bleachbit. Just running `sudo apt-get autoremove` seems safer to me. Though i guess it also depends on how you configure your cleaning inside Bleachbit (there are a lot of options presented with checkboxes for what you want to clean up)

Answer (score 15):

One minor addition: Since 14.04 you may actually write `apt autoremove` to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed as dependencies.

These two commands are equivalent:

- `apt autoremove`
- `apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I'm super late to this party here @matt, but I believe you're meant to use `apt` interactively, and specifically not meant to use `apt` in scripts. The `apt-get` command (and other `apt-*` commands) are designed to have stable behavior in the long term, whereas `apt` is intended to be simpler and more user-friendly, and will continue to evolve or change in ways that humans like. Specifically, they've said that '[`apt`'s] output may be changed between versions' so that's one reason you should avoid it in scripts if you care about the output.