# Can I delete upgraded versions of kernel to free up space?

Tags: boot, kernel

I am using kernel version 4.15.0-99 but kernel versions 4.15.0-106 and 4.15.0-112 got installed. Even after removing all the old versions of kernel, my boot is full now.
Could somebody suggest me a solution?

Comment: Please provide OS & release details, also the size of your /boot (are you on server? desktop?..)  Why not use the latest? are you off-line and don't therefore care about security patches to fix issues?

Comment: Using Desktop with Ubuntu 16.04. Boot partition is of 196MB.

Comment: Yes, you can remove old kernels. Use `du -hs /boot/*` to check what takes up space. The /boot is way too small.

Comment: Why are you using an old kennel when 2 new ones are installed?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the upgraded versions of kernels, but then you might never get kernel upgrades anymore (because certain kernel meta package will be deleted, too; in your case it would probably be linux-generic-hwe-16.04). To get security updates, it is better to use the latest available kernel.

With such low /boot partition size, it might be a good idea to install [linux-purge](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge) and run e.g.

```
sudo linux-purge --keep=1
```

That will purge all kernels except the one(s) depending on the meta kernel(s), and one earlier version of each of those kernels. It will not remove the current booted kernel.

You could run it periodically, e.g. during each boot. How to do that automatically is a matter of a separate question.

If you have a good reason to stick with the kernel version 4.15.0-99, you could use

```
sudo linux-purge --choose
```

to remove the other ones selectively.

Answer (score 1):

Anything no longer needed by the system can be removed by issuing "sudo apt autoremove" to safely remove it from Ubuntu.

Related Article: [What is the advantage of using sudo apt-get autoremove over a cleaner app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527410/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-sudo-apt-get-autoremove-over-a-cleaner-app)

Comment: Note, OP is using an older kennel. `sudo apt autoremove` may delete the old kennel being used.